# Ubuntu 20.04 not detected as bootable device with USB C anymore but USB A still works

Tags: boot, 20.04, uefi, usb-c

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on an external SSD.
Since some weeks it does not show up as bootable drive anymore when I use USB C but with USB A it still works.

It is the same behavior on my PC (3 years old) as well as my notebook (1 year old) - both with latest BIOS.

It is using UEFI.
And I also tried to update grub `sudo update-grub` but nothing changed.

I could not find anything about it with Google.
How can I fix it? =)

Comment: Hello. To be clear it does not work on 2 different computers as a boot device?

Comment: Yes, it does not work on 2 different computer as a boot device using USB-C. But USB-A works...

Comment: If 2 different computers have the problem it is most likely a hardware problem with the drive, Have you looked to see if there is updated software for the SSD drive?

Comment: ssd firmware version is up to date. the thing is, it was working more than 1.5 years including USB-C

Comment: What kernel is being used on each machine?

Comment: Ubuntu is installed on that external SSD. So its the equal OS/Kernel for both machines. `uname -r`  `5.13.0-35-generic`

When I go into the boot manager of the BIOS, it is not detected to boot from.

Comment: If you have another USB-C cable, try that other cable. Maybe the cable is broken (if it worked for 1,5 years an now it doesn't).

Comment: I tried 2 different USB-C cables. Nothing changed. Btw: the USB-A is in the end just using the same USB-C cable + an adapter on it =)